# How can I save data temporary and return it in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am building a simple `express` application that stores the data from a particular server and sent it to `frontend` on request.
Here is my code.

`index.js`

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import { routes } from '../routes';

export let cache = {};

const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use('/', routes);
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening to port ${port}`);
  ... DOING SOMETHING ...
  const result = someFunc();
  cache = result;
});
```

`router.js`

```
... ... ...
routes.get(
  '/cache',
  catchAsync(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const query = req.query?.fields || '';
    const fields = query ? String(query).split(',') : [];
    res.status(200).json(fields.length ? pick(cache, fields) : cache);
  }),
);
```

This works well on `local`, but when I deploy it to `Vercel` it always returns `{}`.
It seems that setting to `cache` is not working on `Vercel`.

How can I implement do this?

Answer (score -1):

The recommended way of caching is by using a in-memory database like Redis. You can go through [this](https://developer.redis.com/develop/node/nodecrashcourse/caching/) to get started.